# How to add to JTable?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a Punnett Square in Java and for that I need to edit cells in a JTable using variables.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class JTableCreatingDemo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Object rowData[][] = { { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3" },
        { "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3" } };
    Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };
    JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(300, 150);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

I'm learning about JTable from that code and is there any way I can add to rowData[][] and columnNames[]?

Or any other way to make a Punnett Square program using JTable?

Edit:

This is the method that includes the table

```
public void f12(List<String> fin, int a){
    JFrame gamFrame = new JFrame();

    Object column[] = {"Gametes", "Gametes"};
    Object rowGam[][] = {};

    final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowGam, column);

    JTable gametes = new JTable(model);

    double d = Math.pow(10,a - 1);
    String[] rowData = new String[2];
    for (int e = a - 1; e > 0; e--){
        d += Math.pow(10, e - 1);
    }
    String a1 = "", a2 = "";

    if (d > 10){
        a1 = fin.get(0);
    }
    if (d == 11){
        a2 = fin.get(1);
    }
    rowData[1] = String.format(a1 + a2);
    model.addRow(rowData);



    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(gametes);

    gamFrame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    gamFrame.pack();
    gamFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The

```
if (d > 10){
    a1 = fin.get(0);
}
if (d == 11){
    a2 = fin.get(1);
}
```

will be a little more complicated later but the table doesn't work with this either.

In the above case, fin = {A, B} and a = 2.

And my expected result is a table with one column (Gametes) and one row below it (AB).

Comment: Please see edit to answer, including code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution: Use a DefaultTableModel object, and then call its `addRow(...)` method if you want to add a new row data to it.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class JTableCreatingDemo {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      Object rowData[][] = {
            { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3" },
            { "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3" } };
      Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };

      final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData,
            columnNames);
      JTable table = new JTable(model);

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
      btnPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add Data") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int rows = model.getRowCount() + 1;
            String[] rowData = new String[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < rowData.length; i++) {
               rowData[i] = String.format("Row%d-Column%d", rows, (i + 1));
            }
            model.addRow(rowData);
         }
      }));

      frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      frame.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
      // frame.setSize(300, 150);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);

   }
}
```

Likewise you can use the other methods of DefaultTableModel such as `removeRow(...)` and `setValueAt(...)`.  If this is not sufficient for your needs, then you'll want to create your own TableModel, one that extends from AbstractTableModel. This will require more work, but can result in a class that is more OOP-compliant.

Comment: I don't know what Override does, but is it necessary to put an override statement? Because, I tried doing it and it kept giving me an error. Also, can it be done without having to press a button?

Comment: @SohamTalele: `"... and it kept giving me an error."` -- if you need help with this, please give us more information, including showing your code attempt and your error message. `@Override` is a message to the compiler that the method immediately below it should override a parent class method. If it's giving you an error, then you're method is not an appropriate method override -- you're doing *something* wrong. And yes, of course it can be done without a button. The button code is in just to demonstrate the use of the TableModel, the latter of which is the key to all of this.